# Speed Up Windows - Disable Services

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, performance, services, speed

In 2007 to 2009 there was an amazing peace of software for windows xp (but it worked perfectly for windows 7 as well) that used to display all the services running on a computer, what it was for and if it was needed or not.

There are similar software packages, but what made this different was that it explained each service accurately and in great detail, and also told you if you could turn it on or off, and what the impact would be.

Example: Shared printer over a network, not needed if you do not print or share a printer over a network.

I have never found another app that accurately gives EVERY service, what it does and what the impact is if it is turned off. Would love if anyone can help with this.

Comment: Welcome to Super User:  Please read How to recommend software (i know you are asking and often this site will provide a good answer)but these day it may help you if you checked :- [softwarerecs.se] and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- [Help], [Answer], [Ask]  again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: Such software does not exist because the documentation to create it does not exist outside of Microsoft. The available documentation is incomplete. Some services have important functions beyond what is documented, which ones of course being undocumented. And in Windows 10 this could change with the next update. Only Microsoft could create such software and they will not and should not.

Comment: Read carefully....http://www.blackviper.com/

Comment: I used it before, so yes it does exist... I understand most of you think it is pointless and dangerous and that there is no increase in performance but this is not true. I had a old pentium 1 laptop that only had windows loaded along with the game need for speed underground. It could not run the game. I carefully used the software to disable absolutely everything that was not needed in windows, and the game ran fine.

Comment: @moab Do you know who absolutely loves that site and many  similar "Windows performance tweaks" sites? Computer repair shops. They make money by restoring functionality that the customer lost when they followed the advice at those sites.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan are you a conspiracy theorist.

Comment: @Moab No, I'm just an observer: btw, it would only be an accusation of conspiracy if I'd accused the computer repair shops and the posters of highly dubious "Windows  tweak" sites of ''working together.'' All I said was that the former happen to benefit from the latter. Get your terms right.

Comment: Never had a problem using advice from the site i linked to, ever.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling services to "speed up Windows" is largely pointless. If you don't use a shared printer over a network, guess what? The service won't use any CPU time and any memory it's sitting on will be reclaimed by the OS if other things need it.

Comment: +1, not only pointless but dangerous as well - you can accidentally remove some important service!

Comment: I understand most of you think it is pointless and dangerous and that there is no increase in performance but this is not true. I had a old pentium 1 laptop that only had windows loaded along with the game need for speed underground. It could not run the game. I carefully used the software to disable absolutely everything that was not needed in windows, and the game ran fine. So, just because you do not like what I am doing does not mean it cannot work or that there is never any benefit.